# finding the sum of a column

Tags: .net

I have three columns in a table first one for start time, second one for end time and the third one for the duration.

Now I want to find out the sum of the duration column, any ideas how can do it?

however I am using .net as programming language

Comment: Sum could mean many things.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: Table of what?  What kind of table?  .net is not a language.

Comment: Meera, you will probably get more helpful answers if you give a little more context to your question. Do you mean sum these in a database query? Is it SQL Server / MySQL? Also pay attention to the tags available. Is the a SQL question, LINQ maybe? (The more effort that goes into the question, the more effort you'll have put into the answer) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(duration)
from tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why three columns should be different but if I got your questions you can use SUM oprator:

```
SELECT SUM(Column3) FROM TABLE1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Me.txtTotalDuration.Text = table.Compute("sum(duration)", String.Empty)
```

Comment: Basically, it seems like you want to perform the sum() function on the 'duration' column and output the result to a string (String.Empty), so you can read it.  You want to do it on a table, so you're using table.Computer.